# How to query just one or two column from a Table in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a table say CATEGORY, and one of its column is CATEGORY_NAME.
I want to query all the category_names from the table.

In SQL I would do-

```
SELECT CATEGORY_NAME FROM CATEGORY;
```

How can I do this in `flask-sqlalchemy`?

My model is:

```
class Category(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
```

I read we can do this with `with_entities`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It worked this way with `with_entities`:

```
cat_names = Category.query.with_entities(Category.category_name).all()
```